# Place label on top of Python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to place my label on top of my plot in another box in Python. My existing plot looks as follows:

[image: my plot]

Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, sol[:,0], 'blue', lw = 3, label='$N$')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,1], 'green', lw = 3, label='$P$')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,2], 'red', lw = 3, label='$Z$')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,3], 'black', lw = 3, label='$Z$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time (days)', fontsize=10.)
plt.ylabel('$N,P,Z,D$ ($\mu$mol N L$^{-1}$)', fontsize=10.)
plt.xlim([0.,365.*sim_years])
plt.ylim([0,16])
plt.xticks(fontsize=10.)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10.)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I want a label to look like this:

[image: Expected label]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib automatic legend outside plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413789/matplotlib-automatic-legend-outside-plot)

Comment: Or maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could experiment with using the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter to [`plt.legend()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html?highlight=legend#matplotlib.legend.Legend). This gives you extra control over the location:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Demo data
sol = np.array([[3,3,4,3], [1,4,2,7], [2,5,3,10], [3,6,4,15], [5,8,2,14]])
t = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, sol[:,0], 'blue', lw = 3, label='$N$')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,1], 'green', lw = 3, label='$P$')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,2], 'red', lw = 3, label='$Z$')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,3], 'black', lw = 3, label='$Z$')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', ncol=4, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.1))
plt.xlabel('Time (days)', fontsize=10.)
plt.ylabel('$N,P,Z,D$ ($\mu$mol N L$^{-1}$)', fontsize=10.)
#plt.xlim([0.,365.*sim_years])
plt.ylim([0,16])
plt.xticks(fontsize=10.)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10.)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This would display as follows:

[image: Demo plot with legend external to the plot]

Here `bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.1)` means half way along horizontally, with `1.0` being at the top, so `1.1` being just above the top. `ncols=4` is used to make it display horizontally.

Comment: Thanks Martin. It works, I really appreciate your response, sorry that the title of my post was a little bit misleading, but thanks for understanding.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down arrow to accept an answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The title of this post is a little bit misleading.

I guess this what you're after: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/pylab_examples/legend_demo.html