# Adjust legend to several graphs (Pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

There are several questions in StackOverflow regarding the position of the legend in Python's `matplotlib.pyplot`. For a single graph, the problem can often be solved by tweaking parameters `location` and `bbox_to_anchor`. In the following example, the legend can be placed above the graph with `bbox_to_anchor = (0.5,1.3)`.

```
industry_capm_df.plot.bar
ax = plt.axes()
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,1.3))
```

[image]

Yet, for this other graph, the same parameters `(0.5,1.3)` result in a legend slightly out of alignment.

```
industry_raw_df.plot.bar
ax = plt.axes()
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,1.3))
```

[image]

Since I got several graphs to plot, I would like legend alignment to be automatic, without having to tweak `bbox_to_anchor` every time. How could I solve this?

Comment: This answer may be useful to you, they describe how to automatically place the legend according to the axis (by transforming to figure coordinates) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846024/11080708

Comment: @Incognito do you want same width and height or only that the left edge be aligned with the axis?

Comment: Only the alignment

Answer (score 0):

You should add `loc='lower left'` to specify that the coordinates in `bbox_to_anchor` refer to the lower left corner of the legend:

```
ax.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.03), borderaxespad=0)
```

`borderaxespad` is to disable padding outside the box, so that the left edge is perfectly aligned with the axis. Then we add a bit of padding (0.03) so that the bottom edge is slightly above the top of the chart.

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Comment: I think OP wants it to vary with the location of the axis so it always lines up.

Comment: @M-Wi Yes, and I think the issue is that width and height change according to the content

Comment: I tried to specify both width and height to 0 and it didn't change anything in the figures

Comment: @Incognito check my new answer pls